# Orthogonal idempotents in rings without unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents, rngs

### Some context

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712624/the-successor-of-0-in-an-ordered-ring/4712640#4712640) and comments, an argument is given for why an ordered ring with unity can't have nontrivial idempotents. I'm trying to extend the argument for an ordered ring $R$ without unity (an "rng"), and I'm fairly certain it can be done as described in the comments: if $\epsilon, \delta \in R$ are nonzero idempotents such that $\epsilon\delta = \delta\epsilon = 0$, then $\epsilon(\delta-\epsilon) = -\epsilon$ and $\delta(\delta-\epsilon) = \delta$, hence $0 \leq \delta - \epsilon \leq 0$ and so $\delta = \epsilon$.

The hurdle is that this only proves that $R$ has *at most* one nonzero idempotent, not *no* nonzero idempotents. This was a problem in the ring with unity case because $1-e$ is idempotent whenever $e$ is. So, my question essentially is, is there still a problem in the "rng" case?

### Question

To be more precise, if $R$ is an "rng", then we say a pair of nonzero idempotents $\epsilon, \delta \in R$ is "orthogonal" if $\epsilon\delta = \delta\epsilon = 0$. I want to know, **if $R$ has a nonzero idempotent $e \in R$, under what conditions does there exist another idempotent $\delta \in R$ orthogonal to $e$?**

The above work shows that no ordered "rngs" have orthogonal pairs. [These](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398617/idempotents-in-rings-without-unity) [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663518/idempotents-in-a-ring-without-unity-rng-and-no-zero-divisors) discuss similar issues, but don't quite address orthogonality. Can we get anything more concrete?